# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Nautilus Shows Locked sed* files that do not exist

Tags: command-line, nautilus, sed

After running a couple of thousand sed commands to make global file changes to my web site, specifically ensuring that every .html file is a valid HTML5 document, Nautilus shows that the folders that I ran the seds against are full of locked files created by sed.  The following screen capture shows multiple such files in my $HOME/public_html/Canada folder:

[image: Nautilus showing locked files]

Now obviously I cannot remove them using Nautilus because it runs under my userid and does not have the authority.

However if I open a terminal I cannot remove them even with sudo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a Nautilus bug, because when I close and reopen Nautilus it agrees with the command line that these files do not exist.